# Show custom message and button text for javascript confirm dialog?

Tags: javascript, confirm

Is it possible to give custom message for buttons instead of Cancel/Ok and give my own text?

I saw lots of tutorials on replacing js confirm with jquery dialog. But isn't there a way with using native JS? I see the same thing done in Grooveshark and many other pages; when user wants to navigate away from their page user is prompted with a js dialog box with custom buttons like 'Stay on page/Leave page'?

Any idea how they might be implementing this? Their dialog box appears as if generated using native JS!

Comment: No, you have to use some custom library in this case, there are tons of them. However you can style them to look like native. But think is it worth trying to mimic all the possible platforms and browsers? No.

Comment: That would be something like jQuery dialog (or other library counterpart), and nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you were seeing a slightly different dialog box.

Add this to your page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but the question how to make custom button labels.

Comment: @dfsq: please read the question carefully. there is a huge chance that op do not know `onbeforeunload`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. Just one more thing, could it be possible to change the text or button labels?

Comment: No, it is not possible to change the text of any "built-in" control.  Not `prompt`, `alert`, `confirm` or the exit-page dialog.

Comment: For that purpose one will have to use some other libraries(like jquery) and style the dialog to look like native js dialog box, right?

Comment: @goose -- On the `onbeforeunload` -- no.  There is nothing else that can replace the built-in dialog boxes.  On order browsers you could, kinda-sorta, but it turned out to be very problematic.  People would refuse to let you leave the page, or they'd open a new tab (with the same stuff) when you tried to leave.  So, in modern browsers, `onbeforeunload` returns a string and the browser takes over the rest.